# Remove and reconnect to TFS project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I'm brand new to TFS but have inherited a visualstudio.com account and am trying to pull down the various projects within it to get them running locally.

In Visual Studio Community 2017 I've logged into the team account and successfully connected to several of the projects and done a 'Map and get' to pull the code down.  However, a couple of the projects seem to be very large and resulted in Visual Studio freezing during the 'map and get' process, to the point where I've had to force quit.

When I load any of the failed projects none of them show any solutions in the Team explorer window, so it looks like there's stuff missing from them on my local machine.  I'd like to try again to connect and 'Map and get' each of these projects, but first I think I probably need to remove the broken ones which are there (unless there's a way to 'fix' them without removing?).  So I've right clicked the ones which failed to complete in the connections list in the 'Team explorer' window and hit 'Remove', which removes them from the list of connections.  However, when I re-connect there's no option to 'Map and get' each of these projects, the failed version is what loads up.  I imagine all I'm doing here is removing and re-adding the connection, whereas what I want to do is remove anything to do with that project locally and try to get it again from scratch.

Can anyone suggest how to safely remove my local versions of the failed projects without affecting anything on the remote TFS server, so I can effectively try to grab the projects again locally from scratch, as if starting again?

*Excuse my (naive/incorrect) use of terminology and explanation here, but I'm just learning all of this stuff from scratch — happy to clarify if I've mis-termed anything or not explained well enough.*

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to remove the connection from the manage connections window, antithetically titled **Connect to a Project**.

#### From Team Explorer Home

- Click the "Manage Connections" plug icon

[image]

- click `Manage Connections` and `Connect to a project`

[image]

- select and context click the project from which you want to disconnect
- select `Remove`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to start from scratch it's to create a new workspace:

1)

[image]

2)

[image]

3)

[image]

4)

[image]

5)

Navigate to the projects, the status will be "Unmapped" and you can map each project and download.